# Nodejs Express Multer file upload - handle response in route based on form data

Tags: node.js, express, multer

My current implementation is as follows:

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({

    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, 'public/images/items/')
    },filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        let ext = ''; 
        if (file.originalname.split(".").length>1)
            ext = file.originalname.substring(file.originalname.lastIndexOf('.'), file.originalname.length);
        cb(null, Date.now() + ext)
    }    
})
```

...Using route....

```
app.post('/updateItemImage', upload.single('image'), function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('user: ' + req.user.id + ' updating image: ' + req.body.item_id);
})
```

..Alright. That works. req.body.item_id is present in my route, and multer handles req.file, saving it to disk with a unique filename.

***however*...**

I'd like the item to be saved using multer, only if req.user.id and req.body.item_id have certain values. req.body.item_id is undefined within the scope of:

```
filename: function (req, file, cb) {
```

So I can't move my code into this function.

**TLDR:** post function needs to capture req.body.item_id, and req.file. If req.body.item_id == value than save file and res.send('ok') There's more than one way to skin a cat. What's an option that would work?

EDIT: here is the frontend js:

```
$scope.uploadFile = function(files) {

            var fd = new FormData();

           var uploadUrl = '/updateItemImage';
           var fd = new FormData();

             fd.append("image", files[0]);
             fd.append("item_id", '11');
            $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
                transformRequest: angular.identity,
                headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
            }).then(function (response) {
                if (response.data == 'ok') {
                      return
                }

                alert('something went wrong')
            })
        }
```

EDIT: Swapping the order of parameters so that the body param was first:
fd.append("item_id", '11');
fd.append("image", files[0]);

Resolved my issue. This shouldn't matter!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> req.body.item_id is undefined within the scope of:
>
> `filename: function (req, file, cb) {`

I've already tested it, it worked, the value is not `undefined` in that scope

[image]

Comment: Nope. req.body.item_id is unequivocally undefined when outside of the route, and defined, returning the proper value from front end, inside the route. Updating post to reflect my frontend js

Comment: Resolved by changing the order of my form object properties in the front end.